# CentOS 8: FUTURE Security Policy AES256-CBC

Tags: centos, ssh, security

I am trying to disable the AES256-CBC cipher used in the OpenSSH server on CentOS 8, while keeping the security policy set to FUTURE.

Based off of the table at [this page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/security_hardening/index#system-wide-crypto-policies_using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies) (see "Cipher suites and protocols enabled in the crypto-policies levels"), it seems that the FUTURE crypto-policy should not enable the CBC mode ciphers (see 'no' in the cell corresponding to 'FUTURE' and 'CBC mode ciphers').

I ran this command to change my CentOS 8 system from DEFAULT to FUTURE:

```
sudo update-crypto-policies --set FUTURE
```

Followed by a reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

However, a Nessus scan shows that the SSH service supports the 'aes256-cbc' algorithm. This output corresponds to [this](https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/70658) Nessus plugin.

After some investigation, it seems that the FUTURE security policy files for the service (and the client) do indeed contain 'aes256-cbc':

```
$ grep aes256-cbc /usr/share/crypto-policies/FUTURE/openssh*.txt
/usr/share/crypto-policies/FUTURE/opensshserver.txt:CRYPTO_POLICY='-oCiphers=aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc -oMACs=umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512 -oGSSAPIKeyExchange=no -oKexAlgorithms=curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com -oPubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com'
/usr/share/crypto-policies/FUTURE/openssh.txt:Ciphers aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
```

I could either make SSH opt-out of the global security policy (and set `Ciphers` in sshd_config manually) or edit the /usr/share/crypto-policies/FUTURE/openssh*.txt files manually to exclude CBC, but I don't like the idea of either of these.

Is this possibly a bug in the Centos 8 security policy configuration, or is there some way to disable CBC without manually specifying a cipher list?

Comment: I have the same problem.
To check which ciphers are in use just type `systemctl status sshd`

Answer (score 5):

After some hours of work, i solved it

You need to create a customized policy inside the directory  **/etc/crypto-policies/policies/modules/**, setting the rules to disable CBC ciphers

Example

```
vim /etc/crypto-policies/policies/modules/NO-CBC.pmod
```

In this file, you should put all the ciphers you want to disable, like this:

```
tls_cipher = -AES-256-CBC -AES-128-CBC
cipher = -AES-128-CBC -AES-256-CBC -CAMELLIA-256-CBC -CAMELLIA-128-CBC
ssh_cipher = -AES-128-CBC -AES-256-CBC
```

After saving that, you need to load the policies with the modification that you created. In my case, i'm using the "FUTURE" policy. You can choose any policy, but don't forget to set up the modifier, like this:

```
update-crypto-policies --set FUTURE:NO-CBC
```

Now, just restart sshd service, and CBC will be disabled.

systemctl restart sshd

Comment: Thanks! This does look like the best solution available currently, but I still don't love it since in theory a new cipher could be added to FUTURE which uses CBC, but it would not be disabled unless I also remember to edit NO-CBC. I would need to keep checking FUTURE to see if there are new ciphers I need to disable - the main goal is for me to not need to worry about individual ciphers.

Comment: You can use `cipher = -*-CBC` now.

Answer (score 2):

Add below in /etc/sysconfig/sshd

```
CRYPTO_POLICY='-oCiphers=aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr -oMACs=umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512 -oGSSAPIKeyExchange=no -oKexAlgorithms=curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com -oPubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com -oCASignatureAlgorithms=rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,rsa-sha2-512,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519'
```

and

```
systemctl restart sshd
```